# Get the Average from Function Results

Tags: python, average

Good day!
I want to get the average if I run the results of a function multiple times

My main function is func. It will calculate the value of y from a generated random number

func will be run by the function repeat for N times

I'm expecting to get the average of this multiple runs if I simply use numpy.average()

```
import numpy as np

def repeat(N, f, *args):
    for i in range(N): f(*args)

def func(num_min, num_max):
    diff = num_max - num_min
    number = num_min + diff*np.random.uniform(0,1)
    y = 2*number
    print(y)

np.average(repeat(10,function,1,4))
```

It gives the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'int'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your function `repeat` does not return anything

Comment: Try: `def repeat(N, f, *args): return [f(*args) for i in range(N)]`

Comment: You never call `func` and never define `function`.

Comment: @AlexandreS: This won't fix it. What is function?

Comment: if I run the line repeat(10,function,1,4), it will give me 10 random numbers:
3.7141562451798493
3.90123290362874
4.126565032519665
4.249539267434587
5.11863942418525
5.831899671725435
6.947204630781044
6.960425237904696
4.974458517972596
7.619483934569705

But if I run the line np.average(repeat(10,function,1,4)), it will give this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'int'

Comment: @justin it will print it, not return it!

Comment: This code seems very long winded. If you want to generate random numbers or floats use the `random` module. Store the numbers in a `list` then use the `sum` of that list and divide it by the amount of numbers in the list. Surely that is easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repeat` will call `func` x time, but you want to keep track of each value `return` by `func`, in this case you should `yield` each results.

`func` should return something if we want to use it later on. Print will show it in the terminal, but it's not assign anywhere, so you can use futher down.

Finaly as `repeat` will be a `generator`, you use list to get all values and then take the mean.

```py
import numpy as np 

def repeat(N, f, *args): 
    for i in range(N): 
         yield f(*args) 

def func(num_min, num_max): 
     diff = num_max - num_min 
     number = num_min + diff*np.random.uniform(0,1) 
     y = 2*number
     return y 

 np.average(list(repeat(10,func,1,4)))
```